# Change value of bootstrap button onclick

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change the content of a button when clicked - specifically I want it to change to a "block" state where it can't be clicked, while I want to give it a Glyphicon.

What I want added:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-saved" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

and the text "Downloaded" - I wish for this to erase the previous text and Glyph icon, and I've found this little peace of jQuery that changed the text on click.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#download-btn').click(function() {
 $("#download-btn").text('Downloaded');
})
});    
</script>
```

but it wouldn't allow me to add any HTML code, it just outputted it as pure text.

And last, I want to add the following style `btn-block` to the button.

This is the button before being clicked;

```
<button id="download-btn" type="button" class="center btn btn-primary">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save" aria-hidden="true"></span> Download
</button>
```

After click, the jQuery above changed the text to "Downloaded", but I can't seem to figure out how I add style, and code, to a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery:

- You can change an elements html with [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)
- You can change an elements styles with [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)
- For changing classes, you can use [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)

There are many more jQuery functions for DOM manipulation.

I'd suggest taking a look. [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `.html()` to apply/override HTML that is inside the element you are selecting.

You can disable buttons in a few ways. I used `.attr()` or you can use `.prop()`.

```js
$('#download-btn').click(function() {
   $(this).html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Downloaded').attr('disabled', true); 
});
```

### [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/bhtn5sr2/1/)

Comment: Press, a suggestion -- I would add the markup for the button in the snippet or just change it to a standard code block, it's a bit deceiving when you click the run snippet button and nothing shows up.